# Custom LinearLayout - inflate layout when children not supplied in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a custom linear layout

```
<com.example.DetailsView
    android:id="@+id/row_ivd_status_details" [...]
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</com.example.DetailsView>
```

It in the constructor calls `inflate` with the default layout, now I'm trying to add possibility to define the layout within the `com.example.DetailsView` tags and detect it to not inflate default layout - but it fails.

I've tried with:

```
Log.i(TAG, "children:"+getChildCount());//also tried with child count
if(findViewById(R.id.ivd_tv_status) == null) {

    inflate(context, R.layout.ivd_layout, this);
}
```

this is called from the constructors. I want for the following layout to not call the `inflate` method

```
<com.example.DetailsView
    android:id="@+id/row_ivd_status_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ivd_tv_status"
        [...] />


</com.example.DetailsView>
```

Can you suggest the method from which I could call the inflate based on the existence of children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the right place is the `onFinishInflate`, at least it worked for my need.